# Changing font name

Tags: vb.net, fonts

in vb.net  ,I have a rich text box for write text and a combo box for font names.
i added fonts to combo box with this code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ff As FontFamily
    For Each ff In System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families
        FontName.Items.Add(ff.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

But i don't know, how to change the font name of the rich text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RichTextBox.Font = New Font(FontName.Text, 10, FontStyle.Regular)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the code below:

```
RichTextBox1.Font = New Font("Font Name", size)
```

Adapt it to your specific conditions: replace `RichTextBox1` with your RichTextBox, "Font Name" with the given item of your ComboBox `FontName`, `size` with the size you want (it might be the current one, that is, `RichTextBox1.Font.Size`).

Answer (score 2):

Font.Name is read only, but Font is not. So I'd do this:

`TextBox1.Font = New Font(FontName.Text, 26.0, FontStyle.Regular)`

Size and style could be hard-coded, or could be filled from their own combo boxes. Put that code in whatever event-driven sub you're using for the user having selected from the combo box (e.g SelectedValue changed)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ff As FontFamily
    For Each ff In System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families
        FontName.Items.Add(ff.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```